# How are themes implemented in CSS

Tags: html, css, themes, filtering

I am currently using variables keeping track of colors for both light and dark themes (e.g. `--light-background-color`, `--dark-background-color`). This isn't too hard with two themes but seems a bit manual and if faced with more themes it becomes impractical.

I have seen things like night shift that apply CSS filters which invert the colors on a webpage. How do these filters work? and how would I go about implementing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go about this is to have a set of general theme color variables, rather than specific color variables for specific themes like you're trying to do here.
You can define these variables in the `body` element and override them with the class or a custom attribute of the body.

Use these variables as you would normally for your other HTML elements, and just change the attribute of the `body` element to apply a different theme.

The important part here is to make sure your theme color variables have corresponding contrasting color variables as well, so that things like white text on a dark background can swap to dark text on a white background.

Here's an example, where primary and secondary theme and contrast colors are defined in the body element, and are overridden when the body has the "dark" class applied to it:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => document.body.classList.toggle("dark"));
```

```css
body {
  --color-primary: #b4e9ce;
  --color-primary-contrast: #000000;
  --color-secondary: #308d43;
  --color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
  /* Other theme colors... */
}

body.dark {
  --color-primary: #202d26;
  --color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --color-secondary: #8f8f8f;
  --color-secondary-contrast: #000000;
  /* Other theme colors... */
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  border: solid var(--color-secondary) 10px;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--color-primary-contrast);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button>Toggle Theme</button>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Single Line CSS will change Light Theme to Dark:

```
<style>
body
{
  filter: invert(1);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this would not work very well for non-grayscale colours, (e.g. red would flip to yellow)